# Entity Framework table inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the following 2 tables TableA and ArchivedTableA.
Basically They are identical tables, but rows from TableA are moved to ArchivedTable to archive them.

How can I represent this in entity Framework so that these 2 classes inherit from the same entity. I am using POCOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not using inheritance in this situation.  If you were to "archive" a record from TableA to ArchiveTableA it would still be in your base table.

Julie Lerman has a good MSDN article of some of the pitfalls of inheritance.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj553510.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would create a base class with common properties for e.g.

```
     public class BaseEntity
    {
         public virtual int Id {get;set;}
         public DateTime CreatedOn  {get;set;}
    }
```

Then create POCO objects which inherit from this base class becouse they have common columns as follows ....

```
public class TableA : BaseEntity
{
   public string NewName {get;set;}
}

public class ArchivedTableA : BaseEntity
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

You obviously needs to do the DbSet Mapping etc in form of EF plumbing on top of this...

Comment: Do you mean to remove the T4 generation?

Comment: Not necessarily. T4 templates are just "Moulds" to generate your EF classes. You can create your own custom T4 templates which uses the inheritance modal as above. For start I would write all the classes by hand once you are happy with your object model then create your T4 templates from that object model.

Comment: thanks again for your reply. so it seems that out of the box, there is no one to achive this? - you would need to create your own T4 generation - right?